# How to jump to a search bar?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a uisearchbar at the top of a uitableview

I have a button which I would like to be able to scroll to the top of the table (thus bringing the searchbar back into view) and then open it for editing. At the moment I have to scroll to the top and then tap on the scroll bar itself.

The scrolling shouldn't be to difficult but what I can't find anywhere is the code to start editing the searchbar. I tried [searchBar makeFirstResponder]; but that crashed it.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `becomeFirstResponder`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go. Sorry this is my first app so my first use of firstresponder related code.

Comment: No dice. For code [searchBar beginFirstResponder]; I get:

*** -[UISearchBar beginFirstResponder]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x139570
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UISearchBar beginFirstResponder]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x139570'

Comment: @user272992: `become`, not `begin`.

Comment: Beautiful! It works. How wonderfully simple. You have all been very kind.